# How to see the "Bundle" output of Hypothesis Python library? (Stateful testing)

Tags: python, testing, stateful, python-hypothesis

When using the hypothesis library and performing stateful testing, how can I see or output the Bundle "services" the library is trying on my code?

Example

```
import hypothesis.strategies as st
from hypothesis.strategies import integers
from hypothesis.stateful import Bundle, RuleBasedStateMachine, rule, precondition

class test_servicediscovery(RuleBasedStateMachine):
    services = Bundle('services')    
    @rule(target=services, s=st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=2)) 
    def add_service(self, s):
        return s
```

The question is: how do I print / see the Bundle "services" variable, generated by the library?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've given, the `services` bundle *isn't* being tried on your code - you're adding things to it, but never using them as inputs to another rule.

If you are, running Hypothesis in verbose mode will show all inputs as they happen; or even in normal mode failing examples will print all the values used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using the bundle in another rule. I did not put it up because I wanted to just show the bundle I am using in my code. Does each instance of test_servicediscovery have a bundle of its own?

Comment: I can see the failing examples and also with debug mode, I am able to see the examples Hypothesis has been trying. But I wanted to know whether a bundle is treated as a class variable or an instance variable. That is the reason I need to print a bundle or see how does it look like during each example run.

Comment: Yeah, it's more like an instance variable. Printing it is very unlikely to be useful though...